# como obtener el usuario de un sistema web para usarlo en un trigger mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy realizando un sistema web que requiere de auditoria.
Se requiere tomar el usuario que inicio sesión para usarlo en los trigger base de datos.
Se que puedo obtenerlo en php con:

`$usuario=$_SESSION['ventas'];`

pero no se como llevarlo al trigger cuando se guarda algo en la base de datos.

Comment: Lo que pides es mucho mas complejo de lo que parece, necesitas ademas una pantalla de login. Y como no muestranos las tablas o dinos que quieres hacer con los trigers. Por supuesto indicanos que has intentado hacer.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de lo que hablas, 
pero creo que quieres usar el usuario en los SELECT, UPDATE, etc, no ?? 
Y lo que no sabes es como añadirlos durante la consulta sql, o no sabes como hacer la consulta misma ?? 

Por ejemplo, para lograr realizar la consulta que quieras, debes crear la query, y entre la query añadir el o los campos deseados, concatenando (juntando) las variables a consultar.
//Ejemplo

```
$query "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE rut = ".$usuario[`rut`];
```

Comment: Me parece le hace falta a la respuesta, dado que quiere esto pero en un trigger

Comment: Tal y como comentó Srsole, faltand datos,yo estoy asumiendo que el desconoce el concatenado en la query. De todos modos pude haberlo comentado, pero espero respuesta del OP

Comment: Consejo cuando falta información es mejor esperar a que la pregunta esté completa para poderle ayudar mejor al op, de todos modos un ejemplo de lo que expones *el concatenar* le ayudaría también

Comment: No lo puse ?? jaja lo borre antes de publicar, vale men